# Magento get categories and list in navigation in .phtml file

Tags: magento

Ok so I've copied and pasted like 10 inserts already for php code to list the main categories or the sub categories under the Default root category.

None of them are displaying my categories and I have all my categories as root categories AND sub-categories under the Default root category to see if both scenarios will work..

Here is my php code I have in my theme .phtml file (1-column so far)

```
                <?php $_categories = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories(); ?>
                <?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                                <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

I know I have them setup right in the admin panel because I have them both as root and subcategories which shouldn't be necessary of course. I'm just trying everything to get them to display and nothing seems to be working..

Anyone know?

EDIT
Ok I found it in topmenu.phtml in the html directory under the template directory in the page directory:

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Where is the getHtml('level-top') code at so I can alter the markup of the li elements?

Answer (score 0):

For change markup, you need rewrite protected _getHtml method in Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu class